# POS tagging and stopwords removal from text documents

Tags: python, python-3.x, stop-words, pos-tagger

I am unable to do pos tagging and stopwords removal from text documents in a code which I developed by getting help from internet sources. I am new to python and I am doing multi-class text classification task so anyone who can guide me regarding how can I do pos tagging and stopwords removal in my code. Any help shall be highly appreciated. Thanks

I have tried multiple ways using nltk to remove stopwords and pos tagging but couldn't succeed.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from nltk import tokenize,PorterStemmer,pos_tag
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import 
CountVectorizer,TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import 
confusion_matrix,accuracy_score,classification_report
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn import model_selection, naive_bayes, svm
from collections import defaultdict
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords


df = pd.read_csv('projectdataayes.csv')
df = df[pd.notnull(df['types'])]
my_types = ['Requirement','Non-Requirement']

#converting to lower case
df['description'] = df.description.map(lambda x: x.lower()) 

#Removing the punctuation
df['description'] = df.description.str.replace('[^\w\s]', '')  

#splitting the word into tokens
df['description'] = df['description'].apply(tokenize.word_tokenize) 

#Stopwords Removal
STOPWORDS = set(stopwords.words('english'))
df['description'] = [w for w in df['description'] if not w in STOPWORDS]

#stemming
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
df['description'] = df['description'].apply(lambda x: 
[stemmer.stem(y) for y in x]) 

print(df[:10])

 ## This converts the list of words into space-separated strings
df['description'] = df['description'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
count_vect = CountVectorizer()  
counts = count_vect.fit_transform(df['description']) 

#tf-idf
transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(counts)
counts = transformer.transform(counts)  

#splitting the data and training the model
#naives-bayes

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(counts, 
df['types'], test_size=0.3, random_state=39) 
model = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train, y_train)
```

The error is:

```
  File "U:/FAHAD UL HASSAN/Python Code/happycsv.py", line 41, in <module>
    df['description'] = [w for w in df['description'] if not w in STOPWORDS]

  File "U:/FAHAD UL HASSAN/Python Code/happycsv.py", line 41, in <listcomp>
    df['description'] = [w for w in df['description'] if not w in STOPWORDS]

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: You know, there is no line `df['description'] = [w for w in df['description'] if not w in STOPWORDS]` in the code you posted... Please post your actual code.

Comment: Dear Sanyash, I have updated my code. It would be great if you can help me to do stopwords removal and POS tagging in this code. I am new to python and facing issues in these tasks. Thanks.